# Calculating angle using Pythagoras' theorem

Tags: c#, math, angle

I'm finishing an assignment. But I've been bashing my head against one problem with it and can't work it out.

I'm supposed to be calculating the angle in degrees and distance between 2 points, rounded to 3 decimal places. Everything is working fine but the angle it's putting out is wrong

```
double angleInRadians = Math.Atan2(point2X, point1X) - Math.Atan2(point2Y, point1Y);
```

This should be correct right? But it just keeps saying 0 when it should be saying 45 degrees. I've checked and the calculation for converting it into degree is correct, it's getting the angle in radians that is playing up

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Well, you can compute a *distance* between *two* points, not an *angle*. Do you have *vectors*, not just *points*?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The delta and the vector are the same thing right? Doesn't Atan2 calculate the vector (delta)?

Comment: The assignment notes say "Calculate the angle we'd have to move in to go from point 1 to point 2 (0 degrees is directly to the right)"

Comment: The information you provided is not enough to calculate an angle, just between two points. You can have it (also between two points and an ax of the coordinate system) if you have a coordinate system to refer to but you did not mention anything about a coordinate system.

Comment: Also Pythagoras theorem is used for distances, and only for 90 degrees angels... I do not know what other kind of angels do you want to calculate with it but it sounds like a bad idea :)... Try "Law of cosines" which is a general Pythagoras theorem for any kind of angels if you know the triangels edges.

Comment: `Math.Atan2` uses an X and a Y, not two X's or 2 Y's. Specifically: `Math.Atan2(Y, X)`

Comment: Ok so here's what the gave me to work with:

I need to know the distance and the angle. It tells me outright that the angle is 45 and the distance is 1.414. I need to design a program that gives me that information from the other info provided which is:

Point1X: 4
Point1Y: 4
Point2X: 5
Point2Y: 5

It also tells me that the deltas of X and Y are both 1.

Now, I got the deltas by subtracting Points 2X and 2Y from Points 1X and 1Y

And I think thats what Math.Atan was also supposed to do

And then I subtract DeltaY from DeltaX but it just gives me zero @_@

Comment: `double angle = Math.Atan2(point2Y - point1Y, point2X - point1X) / Math.PI * 180.0;`

Comment: Thankyou Dmitry but thats what I've done and it just says zero. After I find the angle in radian I convert it into degrees:

double angleInDegrees = angleInRadians * (180 / Math.PI);

Comment: Try some tests: `(1, 0)` and `(0, 1)` should return `135`, `(1, 0)` and `(5, 0)` should return `0`...

Comment: I just tested your calculation and it said 45! I thought it was the same as mine but in a diffrent order, but it seems it's actually different!

Thankyou so much! I'll experiment tomorrow with this and see if I can find out why your calculation worked and mine didnt

Comment: Ok now it crashes when I run the program

It produces the correct result with 4, 4, 5, 5

However, when I went to submit the assignment it said I had to submit it with 2, 2, 1, 1

So I put those in and it crashed, with the console saying the number is too large to put in a decimal

Comment: I tried asking it what the number is without converting it into a decimal, it says it's not a number (NaN)

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* compute angle between two points. But in case of "*angle we'd have to move* in to go from point 1 to point 2" it's

```
double angle = Math.Atan2(point2Y - point1Y, point2X - point1X) / Math.PI * 180.0;
```

Computing this angle is the very thing [Atan2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2(v=vs.110).aspx) is designed for. Some tests:

```
(1, 0), (0, 1) -> 135
(1, 0), (5, 0) ->   0
(5, 0), (1, 0) -> 180
(0, 1), (1, 0) -> -45
```